# How to determine the best direction of arrow head from series of points

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves

Using a CANVAS, I allow a user to draw a line. To show the direction, I would draw an arrow head to the end of the line. The line is drawn with a series of variable x,y coordinates, If I decide the arrow head direction using the last two points, I would sometimes get a good looking arrow head showing the overall direction of the line drawn by user. But if the user inflected drastically between the 2nd to the last point and last point the arrow gets distorted or point to the non overall trend / direction of the line. Can you point me to an algorithm on how to get the best direction of arrow head given a series of points.[image]

Usually the NG part happens when the user hesitates drawing the line at the end part.

Comment: I'd say this is in many ways a CS problem, but is mathematical enough to remain here

Comment: As a start, you might try sampling every so often and making the "curve" piecewise linear (or use splines). Then your question comes down to: "how to do I predict the general direction of a curve given $n$ equidistantly spaced points along it"

Comment: For sufficiently smooth curves this is more doable, but seems ill defined for sufficiently strange curves, even $C^0$ ones. It also depends on what you define to be the end of the curve... after the user finishes drawing the curve, you don't know a priori how long they will continue drawing afterwards.

Comment: The points are finite many,  so draw all possible arrows and let the reader decide which is the best!

Comment: @dmtri I think letting the user decide would be not an option. I mean for human reader you want to arrow to point where the human intended it to.